# Supabase Websocket connection fails

Tags: supabase

I'm building a svelte app where I need to utilize the `supabase.on().subscribe(`  and I always get a failed connection.

```
websocket connection to wss://<projectID>upabase.co/realtime/v1/websocket?apikey={myKey} failed
```

btw, I've enabled the replication settings for my table. I've downgraded supabase.js package but still no luck
the app is setup with Vite.js
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and it was so frustrating because it was not working.

So I opened an issue in GitHub and I got this response, and it worked!!

> there was an issue authenticating realtime connections of new supabase
> projects that was fixed and deployed over the weekend. can you try
> creating a new supabase project and trying again? if that is
> inconvenient, please send an email to supabase@support.io with your
> project ref.

[issue link](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/379)