# How can I retreive a single post from supabase using to display in a dynamic Route using Nextjs14

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes, dynamic, supabase

So I have a Next js Application and I am retreiving posts from supabase Database. When I retrieve all the posts, it works but when I retreive a single pust dynamically using the Id, the screen dispays null.
Folder structure:

In the `app/notes/page.tsx` this is the code that retreives all the posts also known as bounties.

```
import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies  } from "next/headers";
import { createSupabaseAppServerClient } from "@/utils/supabase/supabaseAppRouterClient";

import {createBrowserClient, createServerClient} from "@supabase/ssr";

export default async function Notes() {

    // const supabase1 = createSupabaseAppServerClient(true);
    
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient<any, "public", any>( { cookies},
         {supabaseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
         supabaseKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,});
    const { data } = await supabase.from("bounties").select();
    return( 
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    );
}
```

In the `app/pages/notes/[...id]` This is the code which returns null on the screen when a specific note is called based on its id.

```
import { createServerComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";


export default async function Page(
    {params : {id}} : {params: {id: string}}
    ) {
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient<any, "public", any>( { cookies},
        {supabaseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
        supabaseKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,});
    
    const { data} = await supabase.from('bounties').select().eq('id', 'bounty_id').single();
    return(
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `id` variable to your `eq` filter. Try the following:

```js
const { data} = await supabase.from('bounties').select().eq('bounty_id', id).single();
```

Comment: When I pass it, the i get an error cannot find name id

Comment: I thik your answer is right, but the code worked by simply creating a new database with similar properties as the database I have. I did this by following this solution foolishly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186943/supabase-websocket-connection-fails

Comment: @kaks Hmm, Supabase's API is very stable, and it is unlikely to see the error. Are you sure there is an `id` property on the `bounties` table in the project you are getting errors for? Could you add a screenshot of your table maybe?

Comment: the id field in the bounties table is named as: bounty_id

Comment: @kaks Then you have to pass `bounty_id` to the `eq` filter. I have edited my answer, so try it out.